# Amazon Elastic IP & EBS volumes released when the instance is stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, elastic-ip

I created an EC2 in stance in Amazon, then I attached an EBS volume & an Elastic IP to it.

After 2 days, my EC2 machine was stoped, and just after that, automatically EBS volume & Elastic IP was released and now I can't recover them anymore!!!

I think that Elastic IP is a safe way to keep my machine IP address even if the instance is restarted or stoped... Is this a new behavior of Elastic Ips and volumes?? how could I preserve my Elastic Ips and volumes even if my instance will be stopped or restarted?

Comment: Can you able to start EC2 instance?

Comment: IYes I'm able to start it again with a new IP

Comment: Once you stop an EC2 instance, you have to disassociate Elastic IP address from stopped EC2 instance otherwise you will get charged for Elastic IP.

Comment: I know that when I stop my instance elasticIP is "detached" and I will pay for it until I attach it, in my case, Elastic IP is released/dropped instead of just to be detached!!

Comment: It is very rare case that your IP automatically released you should contact with AWS support for this case, seems to be possible issue on AWS EC2 site

Comment: The behavour you are describing is not normal. I think the only people who can correctly tell you what happened is AWS support. You should contact them.

Comment: Yes I did and I'm still waiting their answer, thank you